# Would an infintely thin horitzontal yagi with zero height respond to vertical signals?

Tags: antenna-theory

I can hear vertical local signals (not skip) on my horizontal yagi, and when i point it at them their signal goes up, so my horizontal yagi has some gain for vertical signals.

If the vertical transmitting antennas in the distance were infinitely thin with no width, and my horizontal yagi was infinitely thin with no height, and there were no reflections, could i receive the vertical signals ?

If so there must be some attenuation so what is it ?

Is the fact that i can hear vertical signals on my horizontal yagi only because it does have some height and therefore does respond a bit to vertical signals, and because it's probably receiving reflected signals which started out as being vertical but whos polarization changed along the way ?

Someone please help before I become a once vertical dude who went horizontal because his brain exploded because he couldn't work it out !!!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the signals you're receiving aren't purely vertical anyway,. It doesn't take much angle on the other guy's to leak plenty of signal into the other pol.

Also, your yagi is imperfect, even as it is. The feed line hangs down vertically - how is it connected? How good is the balun at balancing? The mast is vertical, is it exactly in the centre of the antenna?

Making it thinner won't reduce any of these effects.

Then as you say, reflections from any diagonal object or plane will scatter one polarisation into the other.

Comment: thanks for the reply and all that makes sense, but my original question remains unanswered ...